# loading classes from JAR using Reflections API

Tags: java, reflection, maven-plugin

I have a Maven Plugin that processes some custom annotations.

The plugin uses the Reflections API as follows:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                          .addClassLoaders(urlClassLoader)
                          .addURLs(urls)
                          .forPackages(packages)
                          .addScanners(Scanners.TypesAnnotated);
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(cb);
```

The URLClassLoader is generated based on the JAR file that contains the classes I am inspecting, same with the urls.

The problem is when I try to actually load the classes.

This method call returns the names of the classes that are annotated

```
Set<String> classNames = reflections.get(Scanners.TypesAnnotated.with(MyAnnotation.class));
```

This method call returns an empty Set

```
Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.get(Scanners.TypesAnnotated.with(MyAnnotation.class).asClass());
```

Comment: Do these jars contain their own version of `MyAnnotation`?

Comment: good question. the annotations and the plugin are maven modules under the same parent project. the jar file that the maven plugin is trying to process was built from a project that has a dependency on that annotations module

Comment: You can use `urlClassLoader.loadClass(MyAnnotation.class.getName()) == MyAnnotation.class` to test whether they agree or have different versions.

Comment: @Holger I actually get a ClassNotFoundException on the loadClass() call. I think that tells me what the problem is? The annotation class files aren't being packaged in the JAR. Would the solution be to enforce that a project using the plugin produce a -jar-with-dependencies?

Comment: The parent loader of the `urlClassLoader` should be a class loader which knows your current runtime class, i.e. use `MyAnnotation.class.getClassLoader()` as parent. Adding the class to the jar is not a good idea; that would lead to the scenario of having two different runtime classes.

Comment: @Holger I think one problem I'm running into is that the JAR file that I'm analyzing does not contain all of the dependencies (i.e. imports etc). So, when I call load for the class I'm interested in (the annotated class), the classloader is complaining that it can't find the classes referenced by the imports. I'm not guaranteed to be parsing a JAR with all dependencies (fat jar). So I may have to rethink my plugin?